# Чтение файла, если он занят?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Подскажите, может есть более правильный способ чтения файла?

Я написал функцию для чтения файла, как только этот файл появляется в указанной папке. Но часто случается, что файл еще не сформировался до конца, а мой скрипт уже пытается его прочесть и выпадает в ошибку. Чтобы избежать ошибки чтения я делаю бесконечный цикл и использую try.

Я вот нутром чувствую, что делаю какой-то костыль и наверное есть правильный способ решения такой задачи. Знаете ли вы более правильный способ чтения файла?

```
def read_file(filename, **csvparms):
    """Считываем данные из файла и превращаем их в список
        Выбираем из файла всё сождержимое, превращаем все в список
        возвращаем все, кроме первой строки, поскольку там заголовки
        Пример использования:
            table = read_file('filename.csv', delimiter=';')
    """
    while True:
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(filename)) as f:
                table = list(csv.reader(f, **csvparms))
                print('Открыл файл', repr_select)
                # repr_select = sum(1 for line in table)-1 #количество строк в файле
                return table[1:]
            break
        except:
            print('Не получилось открыть файл', filename)
```

Comment: ну похоже без костыля с  try\except не обойтись, вот есть такие варианты - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256114/10230655

Comment: как вариант еще вот это - но используется сторонняя библиотека - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115521/10230655

Comment: [fuser](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) в цикле с задержкой?

Answer (score 1):

Если знать характер смены значения даты "последнего изменения файла", то от этого можно оттолкнуться, например: если дата изменений не менялась 10 секунд, то можно приступать к манипуляциям с файлом:

```
import os
import time

p1 = "./script46.py"
while True:
    df = os.path.getmtime(p1)
    dn = time.time()
    if (dn - df) > 10:
        print "Editing time - {0}, now - {1}. Lets read file.".format(df, dn)
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    print "."
# .
# .
# .
# Editing time - 1544082490.01, now - 1544082500.22. Lets read file.
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.stat` - status of a file :

`os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=7876932, st_dev=234881026,
st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=501, st_size=264, st_atime=1297230295,
st_mtime=1297230027, st_ctime=1297230027)`

```
import os, csv, time, contextlib

def read_file(filename='asADS1.py', wait=.5, **csvparms):
    """если за период wait сек. os.stat файла не изменился - читать файл"""
    ff = os.path.join(filename)
    new = os.stat(ff)
    while True:
        (old, new) = (new, os.stat(ff))
        if new == old:
            with contextlib.suppress(Exception), open(ff) as f:
                return list(csv.reader(f, **csvparms))[1:]

        time.sleep(wait)
        continue
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая задача. Я делал следеющее:

- перед открытием файла создавал пустой файл с таким же именем, но с расширением .lock
- если программа завершает работу с файлом, то удаляет файл с расширением .lock
- если, перед открытием файла программа находила файл с расширением .lock, то программа пишет в лог и завершает работу